# Aim for, aim at, aim to

Tags: word-choice, phrases, prepositions

I was asked what the differences are in usage between these three, but I think I probably confused things more than I helped. I guess mostly it's a matter of style? I wondered if anyone had a good explanation.

Comment: More food for thought [here](http://www.proz.com/forum/translation_theory_and_practice/116300-difference_between_aim_at_%2Bing_and_aim_%2B_infinite.html) and [here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/SubtleDifferencesAimsAims/klhpk/post.htm).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You aim for a goal. If you aim for the stars, that's what you want to achieve: high success.

You aim at a target. If you aim at the stars, you'll unlikely hit them, as they are far away.  You arrow will hit the ground.

But you could also aim at doing something

You aim to reach a goal. You need a verb. You aim to succeed but you aim for success. And you aim at succeeding. (Although, the last phrase doesn't have the same thing to it.)

Comment: Nice and clear, thanks! Better received than my effort :)

Comment: I might be slow, but what's the difference between "You aim to succeed" and "You aim at succeeding" ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel: In my opinion it's a question of style, they mean the same thing. I can't think of any examples where they are not interchangeable.